# Phillips hue Local network

Tags: arduino, local-network, philips-hue

I want to send signals to a Phillips Hue Bulb from an Arduino Ethernet, but using only a local network. This means I plan to have a router with an Ethernet connection to both the Arduino and the Hue's bridge, but the router has no connection to the Internet. I read their API's page: http://developers.meethue.com/howhueworks.html and from that I think this could work, but I would like to be sure before buying a Hue kit. Anyone who owns one could assert this will indeed work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this will work :)

You only need internet to update the firmware of the bridge or if you want to control your lights from outside your own network.

You do need a way to find the ip address of your bridge though. So it's probably easiest to give your bridge a static ip or configure your router to always give the same ip to your bridge.